# How to iterate through a Collection<Set<IConnection>>

Tags: java, collections, red5

I have something like this:

```
something need here  = scope.getConnections();

//getConnections() returns Collection<Set<IConnection>>
```

I need to iterate through all connections (the stuff that the `getConnections()` returns)

How to do that ?

Comment: Do you have and IDE? Most of them helps writing return type value and the also can insert collection-loop-code.

Comment: :) yes, i have eclipse, i'm just very new to java, and eclipse

Comment: Are you reinventing the connection pool? I'd recommend using a 3rd party thoroughly developed, tested and maintained connection pooling framework, such as C3P0 or Proxool.

Comment: no i'm just trying to use the red5 media server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (Set<IConnection> set : scope.getConnections()) {
   for (IConnection iConnection : set) {
      // use each iConnection
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Collection<Set<IConnection>> sets = scope.getConnections();

for (Set<IConnection> set : sets) {
  for (IConnection connection : set) {
     //do something
  }
}
```

Comment: And where is your 'generics'?

Comment: The generics was there, but Bozho did not use the code-style properly. I fixed that for him.

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry. I was in a hurry and didn't check :)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to you not to return connections in the way you do.
Your getConnections has to return only

```
Collection<IConnection>

public Collection<IConnection> getConnections()
{
    return connections;
}
```

Inside your class you can select the way you want or need to store them

```
private Set<IConnection> connections;
```

Consider double loop as a problem in your class design.
If I as a user of your class has to write double-loop every time I will stop using your class. So will do your colleagues.

```
for (IConnection connection : provider.getConnections()) 
{
    connection.doAction();
}
```

Comment: scope.getConnections() is from a referenced library so i can't do that, i am just using it

Comment: Ok. I get it. If you just need all of the connections I would recommend to write a wrapper class or Util method two loop over the connections.

Answer (score 0):

The two-nested-for-loops answer is probably all you need, but note that you could also pass the 'connections' collection to Iterables.concat() in google-collections, and get out a single "flattened" iterable.

http://google-collections.googlecode.com